# Javascript map & aggregate nested JSON

Tags: javascript

I'm newer to javascript and using JSON datasource trying to aggregate data in which i'd like to loop through nested JSON and add each "vm" element to another in a list, but keep getting the values repeated next to each.

```js
let jsonData = [{
    "data": [{
            "name": "13_WH1",
            "attributes": {
                "bv": 145
            },
            "vm": [
                3.0,
                2.0,
                5.0,
                5.0
            ]
        }

    ],
    "name": "category_one"
},

{
    "data": [{
            "name": "13_WH1",
            "attributes": {
                "bv": 145
            },
            "vm": [
                4.0,
                8.0,
                6.0,
                6.0
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "32_WH2",
            "attributes": {
                "bv": 155
            },
            "vm": [
                5.0,
                7.0,
                7.0,
                2.0
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name": "category_two"
}
]


function sumVm(data_set) {
  data_set.map(function(series, index) {
    const total_vm = series.data.reduce(
      (accumulator, record) => accumulator + record.vm,
      0
    );
    console.log(total_vm)
    return total_vm

  })
};

console.log(sumVm(jsonData))
```

When you execute the above code snippet you'll see the result doesn't add up each "vm" position.  My desired output would be like this:

```
12,17,18,13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but what you need to do is have the `reduce` at the top-most level. It's a good hint that you don't want a `map` there because you end up with only one array. Within the reducer, iterate through the series and then, within the series, iterate through the `vm` array.

```js
let jsonData=[{data:[{name:"13_WH1",attributes:{bv:145},vm:[3,2,5,5]}],name:"category_one"},{data:[{name:"13_WH1",attributes:{bv:145},vm:[4,8,6,6]},{name:"32_WH2",attributes:{bv:155},vm:[5,7,7,2]}],name:"category_two"}];

function sumVm(data_set) {
  return data_set.reduce((acc, series) => {
    series.data.forEach(el => {
      el.vm.forEach((v, i) => {
        acc[i] = (acc[i] || 0) + v;
      })
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(sumVm(jsonData))
```